# Error in get post by met_key

Tags: metabox

I have this code,

```
    $type = get_the_ID();
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $units3 = new wp_query( array(  'post_type' => 'units' ,
                                    'posts_per_page'=> 6 ,
                                    'paged' => $paged  ,
                                    'meta_key' => 'unittype',
                                    'meta_value' => $type ) ); 
    while ($units3->have_posts()) : $units3->the_post();
```

Its must get me all post from `unit` That is in the unit type that `id = $type` 
But the query is get me all post.

It must get me only all post from unit post type that in unit type post type,

Where is error

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand this sentence-- "It must get me only all post from unit post type that in unit type post type,"-- and honestly the query looks correct to me, but I would suggest trying a `meta_query` and specifying the type, as well as disabling sticky post juggling. If you have 6 or more sticky posts you could have the illusion of the query returning "all" posts.

```
$units3 = new wp_query(
  array(  
    'post_type' => 'units',
    'posts_per_page'=> 6,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'unittype',
        'value' => $type,
        'type' => 'numeric'
      )
    )
  ) 
);
```